# Match documents with their inner array element variables in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I can't understand how to compare a document variable to another document variable. My goal is to match all Authors who have at least one book written in their mothertongue (native language).

However, after unwinding the books array, My `$match: { mothertongue: "$bookLang"}}` doesn't return return anything, eventhough they're the same in the `$project` stage.

Can you help me without javascript?

This is my current query:

```
db.author.aggregate([
 {
  $unwind: "$books"
 },
 {
  $project: {
    books: true,
    mothertongue: true,
    bookLang: "$books.lang"
  }
 },
 { 
  $match: { mothertongue: "$bookLang"}
 }
 ])
```

And here is a sample of the dataset

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aa7b34a338571a7470be0eb"),
        "fname" : "Minna",
        "lname" : "Canth",
        "mothertongue" : "Finnish",
        "birthdate" : ISODate("1844-03-19T00:00:00Z"),
        "deathdate" : ISODate("1897-05-12T00:00:00Z"),
        "books" : [
                {
                        "title" : "Anna Liisa",
                        "lang" : "Finnish",
                        "language" : "finnish",
                        "edition" : 1,
                        "cover" : "Hard",
                        "year" : 1895,
                        "categorytags" : [
                                "Finland"
                        ],
                        "publisher" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "Tammi",
                                        "pubId" : ObjectId("5aa7b34a338571a7470be0e4")
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "title" : "The Burglary and The House of Roinila",
                        "lang" : "English (UK)",
                        "translator" : ObjectId("5aa7b34a338571a7470be0ee"),
                        "cover" : "Soft",
                        "year" : 2010,
                        "categorytags" : [
                                "Finland"
                        ],
                        "publisher" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "Jonathan Cape",
                                        "pubId" : ObjectId("5aa7b34a338571a7470be0e7")
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "title" : "Anna Liisa 2 ed.",
                        "lang" : "Finnish",
                        "language" : "finnish",
                        "edition" : 2,
                        "cover" : "hard",
                        "year" : 1958,
                        "categorytags" : [
                                "Finland"
                        ],
                        "publisher" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "Otava",
                                        "pubId" : ObjectId("5aa7b34a338571a7470be0e9")
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

End goal. **note** I'm not interested in formatting just yet, just the filtering

```
{
        "Author" : "Charles Bukowski",
        "BooksInMothertongue" : [
                "Love Is a Dog from Hell"
        ]
}
{
        "Author" : "Minna Canth",
        "BooksInMothertongue" : [
                "Anna Liisa",
                "Anna Liisa 2 ed."
        ]
}
...
```

Comment: can you add sample result?

Comment: Sample result is with my current query is "", as nothing is returned.

The end goal is something like this { "Author" : "Minna Canth", "BooksInMothertongue" : [ "Anna Liisa", "Anna Liisa 2 ed." ] }  **but** I'm not concerned with the end result yet, just filtering the authors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
db.author.aggregate([{
        $match: {
            books: {
                $ne: []
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            books: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$books",
                    as: "book",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: ["$$book.lang", "$mothertongue"]
                    }
                }
            },
            fname: 1
        }
    }, {
        $unwind: "$books"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            Author: {
                $first: '$fname'
            },
            BooksInMothertongue: {
                $push: "$books.title"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Hi, it grouped all the books in all authors in to a single document without any kind of filtering, so this unfortunately is not helpful to me.

Comment: After replacing 'TEST' with 'author', the result is now the same as before, except _id is '_id' and author is 'null'. Thanks for trying

Comment: @Konsta check now, Sorry i missed to project $fname and id

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you so much Rahul!